# KivyMD: detect when user reaches end of scrollview

Tags: python, kivymd

I have a huge database that is being shown in a `MDGridLayout`. Here's how my hierarchy looks like:

```
ScrollView:
  do_scroll_x: False
  MDGridLayout:
```

I want to detect when the user reaches the end of the scroll and load more items from the database.

How can i detect if the user is at the end of the scroll view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    on_scroll_y: if args[1] <= 0: print("End list")
```